# Cast Any to RawRepresentable where RawValue == String

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I am trying to encode data. For the sake of the example I'll use JSON encoding even though there are other solutions for this out there.

I would like to handle enums that are backed by `String` or an `Int` as if they were simply `String` and `Int`:

```
struct UnhandledValueError: Error {}

enum Foo: String {
  case bar
}

func encode(_ data: Any?) throws -> String {
  guard let data = data else {
    return "null"
  }
  if let string = data as? String {
    return "\"\(string)\""
  }
  if let int = data as? Int {
    return String(int)
  }
  // represent String and Int based enums there

  if let array = data as? [Any?] {
    return try "[\(array.map({ try encode($0) }).joined(separator: ","))]"
  }
  if let dict = data as? [String: Any?] {
    return try "{\(dict.map({ "\"\($0.key)\": \(try encode($0.value))" }).joined(separator: ","))}"
  }

  throw UnhandledValueError()
}

let value: Any? = ["foo": Foo.bar]
try encode(value)
```

Because `RawRepresentable` is a generic protocol I don't think I can do either

```
if let value = data as? RawRepresentable
```

or

```
if let value = data as? RawRepresentable where RawValue == String
```

How can I access the raw value (as `Any`?) from an object that might be `RawRepresentable` ?

Comment: Sure. I'm not using Codable though but rather doing the encoding myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a generic method and constrain its type to RawRepresentable where its RawValue conform to LosslessStringConvertible:

```
func encode<T>(object: T) -> String where T: RawRepresentable, T.RawValue: LosslessStringConvertible {
    .init(object.rawValue)
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
enum IntEnum: Int {
    case a = 1, b, c
}

enum StringEnum: String {
    case a, b , c
}

let int: IntEnum = .c
let string: StringEnum = .c

encode(object: int)      // "3"
encode(object: string)   // "c"
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question with more context to show how I want to call this recursively on both enum and non enum values.

Comment: Forget about using Any. You are going the wrong path

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and show your original JSON. You should struct your data. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If you really want to go this path of using Any just use the regular JSONSerialization method dataWithJSONObject `try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject)`. You would still need to make sure your objects are valid JSON objects.

Comment: This is part of a framework where I've no control on the input data. I cannot use the built in JSON serialization as I need to support only certain types, and throw errors for unsupported cases where JSONSerialization would succeeded.

Comment: @Guig show the input data. I am sure there is an easier way to accomplish the encoding